# Proof: if $x^5-4x^4+3x^3-x^2+3x-4≥0$ then $x≥0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

I have proved this question by finding the solution of the polynomial using 17 steps Newthon Rhapson and found out that x ≥ 3,0735. I am wondering is there any more simple way to solve this?

Comment: See what happens if $x<0$ (prove the contrapositive statement). Hint: look at the signs of the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: @Malkoun this should be an answer prefaced with "Hint" in my opinion

Comment: @RhysHughes, done. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: prove the contrapositive statement. If $x<0$, then the polynomial on the left-hand side takes on a negative value at $x$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x^5-4x^4+3x^3-x^2+3x-4 \geq 0   \Rightarrow x(x^4+3x^2+3) \geq (4x^4+x^2+4)  \Rightarrow x \geq \frac{4x^4+x^2+4}{x^4+3x^2+3}$. Since the expression on the right hand side is always possitive, it indeed shows $x\gt 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$p(x) = x^5-(1+x+x^2)(4-7x+4x^2) $$
and both $1+x+x^2$ and $4-7x+4x^2$ have negative discriminants, so they always take positive values. If follows that for any $x<0$ we have $p(x)<x^5<0$, so $p(x)\geq 0$ clearly implies $x\geq 0$.

Comment: Actually $x\gt3$ and there are some values greater than $3$ for which  $p(x)$ is still negative.

Comment: @Piquito: all right, but the OP only needs to prove that $p(x)\geq 0$ implies $x\geq 0$.

Comment: Of course. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-Equivalently you have $$x^5+3x^3+3x\ge4x^4+x^2+4\Rightarrow x\ge0$$ and it is clear that the quintic is greater than the quartic from a certain positive value of $x$ (this value is a little more than $3$.

Comment: I am sorry but finding in a rigorous way this value "slightly" greater than $3$ is as difficult as the initial problem.

Comment: No, when you ask that $x$ be positive. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

You have that
$$
\begin{gathered}
  p(x) = x^5  - 4x^4  + 3x^3  - x^2  + 3x - 4 =  \hfill \\
   \hfill \\
   = x^3 \left( {x^2  - 4x + 3} \right) - \left( {x^2  - 3x + 4} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
Now:

1. $$-\left( {x^2  - 3x + 4} \right)<0 \;\;\forall x\;\; \in \mathbb R$$
2. $$
   {x^2  - 4x + 3}>0\;\; \forall x\;\;<0$$
3. $$x^3<0 \forall x\;\;<0$$
   Therefore, for every x<0 you have that p(x)<0. Hence, if p(x)=0 it must be x>0

In order to prove that if p(x)=0 then x>3 we have that

1. If $$ 0< x <1 $$ then $$ f(x) > 0 $$
2. If $$ 1< x <3 $$ then $$ f(x) < 0 $$
3. If $$x=0, x=1,x=3$$ then $$f(x)=0$$
4. f   has a local maximum at 
   $$
   x_0  = \frac{1}
   {5}\left( {8 - \sqrt {19} } \right)
   $$
   and
   $$
   f(x_0 ) = \frac{{2\left( {2147\sqrt {19}  - 8986} \right)}}
   {{3125}} < \frac{1}
   {2}
   $$
5. $$g(x)=-(x^2-3x+4) \leq -\frac{7}{4} \forall x \in \mathbb R$$

Therefore if
$$
0 \leqslant x \leqslant 3
$$
it is
$$
p(x) = f(x) + g\left( x \right) \leqslant \frac{1}
{2} - \frac{7}
{4} < 0
$$
It follows that if p(x)=0 then x>3

Comment: I got a mistake while I'm writing. Instead -(x^2-3x+4)<0 for all x I wrote (x^2-4x+3)<0!!! Sorry